# Parsing multiple groups from a regular expression

Tags: regex, pcre

I am having a problem parsing some fields from the following regular expression which I uploaded to [**rubular**](http://rubular.com/r/UD3YOuX0wh).  The string that I am parsing is a special header from the banner of an FTP server. In order for me to process this banner, the line

```
special:pTXT1TOCAPTURE^:mTXT2TOCAPTURE^:uTXT3TOCAPTURE^
```

I thought that: `(?i)^special(:[pmu](.*?)\^)?*` would do the trick, however unfortunately this only gives me the last match and I am not sure why as I am lazily trying to capture each group.  Also note that I should be able to capture an empty string also, i.e. if for ex the match string contains :u^

Wrap words  Show invisibles  Ruby version 
Match result:
special:pTXT1TOMATCH^:mTXT2TOMATCH^:uTXT3TOMATCH^
Match groups:

1. :uTXT3TOMATCH^
2. TXT3TOMATCH

The idea is that the line must start with the test 'special' followed by up to 3 capture groups delimited with p,m or u lazily up to the next ^ symbol.  I need to capture the text indicated above - basically I need to find TXT1TOCAPTURE, TXT2TOCAPTURE, and TXT3TOCAPTURE.  There should be at least one of these three capture groups.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it is Ruby then what is PCRE tag?

Comment: Actually the expression should be pcre compliant - the actual runtime uses pcre on my pc.  I should have made that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems with your RegEx, one is syntactic and one is conceptual.

**Syntactic**:

We don't have such a modifier `?*` in PCRE but it is equal to `*` in Ruby which denotes a greedy quantifier. In the case of applying to a capturing group it captures last match.

**Conceptual**:

Using a lazy quantifier `.*?` doesn't provide you with continues matches. It stops immediately on engine satisfaction. While `g` modifier is on next match will never occur as there is no `^special` at the next position of last match.

Solution is using `\G` token to benefit from its mean of start matching at the end of previous match:

```
(?:special|(?!\A)\G):([pmu][^^]*\^)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/bH6qU7/1)

Comment: If you look at my comment on OP you'll notice its older than your answer. That means I saw question earlier and probably decided to write something. And in reply to your question, if you look closely you'll find differences more in *provided details*. Your RegEx also doesn't satisfy OP's requirements *entirely* which mine does in return. @Jan

Comment: can you help me understand how the (?:^special|(?!\A)\G) works.  In particular I am unfamiliar with the (?!\A)\G' syntax.  The mouse over text in the live demo is not very clear on how that works.

Comment: If engine - at the very first place - tries to match at the beginning of string it sees `^special`, matches it, and then continues with the rest of pattern. As we have `g` modifier on (it should be set) after a satisfactory *walk* it continues from the place that previous walk was successfully finished (right after `pTXT1TOCAPTURE^`). To begin a new match engine starts from beginning of RegEx again. It hits `^special` but doesn't see it in string then goes to second side of alternation, it sees `(?!\A)\G` and it matches. `\G` exactly means *beginning of string* OR *end of previous match*.

Comment: `(?!\A)` denotes to not *beginning of string* so a `(?!\A)\G` only means *end of previous match* (note in this way `\G` never matches beginning of string any more and by this mean we prevent `\G` from matching beginning of string). The engine continues with rest of pattern and this flow repeats till all matches are found.

Comment: any chance you could tell me how to make the live demo work with javascript?  If I change the demo to javascript I get only 1 match  p7038231-1902^ I had a recent request to change the regex engine to javascript

Comment: Unfortunately `\G` token is not supported by javascript thus it's not possible. @johnco3

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have the `\G` modifier:

```
(?:(?:^special:)|\G(?!\A)\^:)[pmu]([^^]+)
```

See it working on [**rubular.com**](http://rubular.com/r/W7EP1OiDDa).